# Resolve Warning: 1082: Migration issue: Method gameThread will behave differently in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

Since I moved to using adobe flash 2017+, I've gotten warnings 1082/1083.
The warning is:
`Warning: 1082: Migration issue: Method gameThread will behave differently in ActionScript 3.0 due to the change in scoping for the this keyword. See the entry for warning 1083 for additional information.`

Although the only error which I am getting is for putting events inside classes, I cannot add mouse events or any events without having these warnings and I don't know how to fix...
People suggested to remove `super()` which is not the solution.

Example of event which I added to main code
error comes on line " addEventListener...."

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import data.Player;


    public class Game extends MovieClip {

        private var players:Array = new Array();

        public function Game() {
            super();

            resetPlayers();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.gameThread);
        }

        private function resetPlayers():void{
            for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++){
                if (getChildAt(i) is Player){
                    players.push(getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

        protected function gameThread(event:Event):void{
            for (var i:int = 0; i < this.players.length; i++){
                players[i].fall();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinWang, please also format code when you make edits.  Your phrasing changes look helpful, but the question still looks sloppy with "package {" outside the code box.

Answer (score 0):

You are be able to overcome this issue by simply removing the **this** keyword. It's not needed in this case.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameThread);
```

In AS3 methods are exectued in the context (your **Game** class) it's defined.
Same for the other uses of the this keyword.
players is a class variable of Game, resetPlayers() and gameThread() are methods of Game -> so it's all in the same context.

Comment: That doesnt really changes anything... The error always comes no metters how i try to write the function (with or without using this.)

Comment: That's really strange. I couldn't find a way to force that error on my side. Maybe the warning messages are suppressed. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using adobe animate CC